# Eclipse - Universal Preferences Across All Workspaces?

Tags: eclipse, preferences, workspace

I like to use several different workspaces, so as to keep everything organized. However, its annoying to have to copy the .settings folder to all my workspaces just because I added a keyboard shortcut. I'm looking for a way to update the preferences of all my workspaces whenever I change the preferences in one workspace. The settings I care about are keyboard shortcuts, code style, fonts, etc.

I have found [this plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/1003) which might be useful, but doesn't seem to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Ideally, I could have my settings saved in the cloud somewhere. On startup, Eclipse will check if workspace settings and the settings in the cloud differ, and if so, import them from the cloud. If I change any settings, then these preferences should be exported to the cloud. This way I also have my preferences on my school's lab machines.

Does anybody know a way to make this work? I'm all ears.

Thanks

Comment: You could try to make a hard folder link between all the .settings folders.

Comment: You could also sync Eclipse folder using something like Dropbox or Copy and then share that folder on all machines you use. You could do this also with a shared network location and hard links (Be sure to sync these folders and not read them from network since that will slow eclipse starting process). I also came here to find a Cloud sync for snippets on my machines but there appears to be no such thing for eclipse. Also you could use Eclipse like any portable program, just use it from a USB stick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.  The easiest thing is probably just manually configure your preferences on those two or three PCs where you use Eclipse, and move on.

Longer answer: yes, you *can* copy (and standardize) Eclipse settings (e.g. for a standard configuration across your development shop).  Here's a good article explaining how:

http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18678.html

Finally, there's *still* no easy way (AFAIK) to safely and reliably UNINSTALL plug-ins as of the latest/greatest version (Indigo, Eclipse 3.7).  So if you find yourself experimenting with a lot of plug-ins .. some of which you might ultimately wish to get rid of ... then maybe your best bet is installing Eclipse on a VM (say, VBox or VMWare, running Linux or Windows).  Use your VM as a little "sandbox" where you can try stuff out, and easily clone (if you like it) or blow it away (if you don't).

IMHO...